# Symfony 3 - must be an instance of FormFactoryInterface, instance of FormFactory given

Tags: php, forms, symfony, service

I want to get my form out of a Service, but whatever I do, it just won't work.

I have the service in the YML

```
services:      
  myservice:
     class: AppBundle\Service\Myservice
     arguments: ["@doctrine.orm.entity_manager","@form.factory"]
```

then in AppBudle\Service\Myserivce.php:

```
namespace AppBundle\Service;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;

class Myservice {

protected $em;
protected $formFactory; 

public function __construct(EntityManager $entityManager, FormFactoryInterface $formFactory) {
    $this->em = $entityManager;
    $this->formFactory = $formFactory;
    }   


// GENERATE CALCULATOR FORM
public function generateCalculatorForm() {  


     return  'ffffsdsd';
    }
```

}

But I get a

> Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 2 passed to AppBundle\Service\Myservice::__construct() must be an instance of AppBundle\Service\FormFactoryInterface, instance of Symfony\Component\Form\FormFactory given, called in D:\xamp\htdocs\icp\var\cache\dev\appDevDebugProjectContainer.php on line 409 and defined

What is wrong here? I already tried almost everything i found on the web, but cant get this working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php

Class/interface name is prepended by current namespace name if its name is not full.

Set full name for `FormFactoryInterface` or add it in `use` statements

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormFactoryInterface;
```